# Take screenshot using helium in python

Tags: python, selenium, helium

I am trying to take a snapshot of a specific element within the page using helium in python and here's my code

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from helium import *

url = 'exampleurl'
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"

browser = start_chrome(url, headless=False, options=options)
#.FindElementById("viewPane").ScrollIntoView True
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmCaseNo']/div[2]/img")
#element.get_screenshot_as_file("Number.png")
#element.screenshot('Number.png')
#element.save_screenshot('Number.png')
#get_driver().save_screenshot('Number.png')
get_driver().element.save_screenshot('Number.png')
```

This line succeeds with helium `get_driver().save_screenshot('Number.png')` but this line doesn't deal with specific element. How can I deal with a specific element and take snapshot of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Helium exposes all the selenium methods also , so if you check webelement class

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html

you can see there is method called

```
  webelement.screenshot("hellium.png")
```

, which will save the elements screenshot as helium.png

so in your case use:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmCaseNo']/div[2]/img")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.screenshot("Number.png")
```

element.screenshot("hellium.png")

**full code:**

```
from helium import *
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import copyfile
#copying it to current directory so that you don't have to do it
copyfile(r"C:\Users\Downloads\chromedriver.exe", "chromedriver.exe")
options=Options()

options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
browser = start_chrome("https://www.google.com",options=options)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//body").screenshot("test.png")
```

Comment: I already tried that in the code (if you see the comments) but doesn't work for me. I got this traceback `WebDriverException: Message: unknown command: session/e25b6f775a4c812c330cb5354768f39e/element/0.5620545447977139-1/screenshot` at this line `element.screenshot("Number.png")`

Comment: @YasserKhalil try updating helium , 
`from helium import *

browser = start_chrome("https://www.google.com")

element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//body")

element.screenshot("hellium.png")`

Comment: Thanks a lot but I got the same error. The weird thing is that when I used selenium not helium, it works well without any problems.

Comment: (3.0.5) i am using this version

Comment: uninstall selenium and helium and then reinstall helium and see

Comment: `pip show helium` you can use these command to see installed version

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the same version 3.0.5. I have uninstalled selenium and helium then installed helium only (which indicates to installation of helium 3.0.5 and selenium 3.141.0 then when trying the code I got `Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary` and this is solved before by setting the options of chrome as I did in my question, so I expect the problem will be the same.

Comment: @YasserKhalil thats interesting , if you keep chromedriver in current directory and don't pass chromeoptions then the code works elese you will get no command error!

Comment: Do you mean I should put the chromedriver in the same path of the python file. By the way, I am using Jupyter Notebbook(maybe this is related to the issue)

Comment: @YasserKhalil yes download latest chromedriver for your chrome version keep in the same directory path as your python file. Or add chromedriver path to environment variable PATH .

Comment: I havea added my full code please have a look

Comment: 88.0.4324.182  is my chrome version

Comment: I didn't get the copyfile line. Will the code copy the chromedriver.exe to that path `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`?

Comment: I have tested the code and now it is working well. But why have I to put the chromedriver.exe in the same path of the python file? And why it didn't work although I put the path of the chromedriver into PATH

Comment: @YasserKhalil it seems helium is shipped with its own chromedrivers , when we use new chrome driver version it behaves differently i am not sure why it doesn't work with shipped chromedriver version

Comment: if you do pip show helium  and goto that location and check chrome driver it shows chromedriver --version as 2.38 something its too old, if you goto start_chrome() source putting chromedriver.path is mentioned as work around

Comment: I did `pip show helium` and I found the location like that `c:\users\future\anaconda3\lib\site-packages` but I didn't find the chromedriver and when tried `chromedriver --version`, it shows me `'chromedriver' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: no :D lib\site-packages\helium\\_impl\webdrivers you have to go inside the helium folder like this

Comment: you can see webdriver  inside that folder

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Now I got the version `ChromeDriver 2.38.552522` in the folder `\site-packages\helium\_impl\webdrivers`. Will I replace this with the newer one of chromedriver.exe?

Comment: You can try that ! I didn't try that should work

Comment: Amazing. That solved the both problems (Now I don't have to use Options() and it is dealing with capturing the screenshot without any problems as all). And that is my final working code `from helium import *

driver = start_chrome("https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmCaseNo']/div[2]/img")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.screenshot('Number.png')`

Comment: If you keep chromedriver in current directory then also you don't have to use chrome options glad it worked :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the great support and for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround by cropping the specific element but I welcome any other ideas (maybe there are simpler solutions)

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from helium import *
from PIL import Image

myCaseNumber = '181564540'
url = 'https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp'
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"

browser = start_chrome(url, headless=False, options=options)
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmCaseNo']/div[2]/img")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
location = element.location
size = element.size
get_driver().save_screenshot('Temp.png')
x = location['x']
y = location['y']
width = location['x']+size['width']
height = location['y']+size['height']
im = Image.open('Temp.png')
im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))
im.save('Number.png')
```